# How can I attach a header to all published messages?

Tags: masstransit

I have a particular header that I'd like to attach to all messages that I publish. I can attach this header on a case-by-case basis by specifying it in the `Publish` call:

```
_bus.Publish(myMessage, context => context.SetHeader("my key", "my value"));
```

This works fine but it becomes a chore to maintain this `SetHeader` call for every publish. Is there a way, during bus configuration or anywhere else, to specify a header that will be attached to all messages? That is, is there a way to do something like the following?

```
ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
{        
    sbc.UseRabbitMq();
    sbc.ReceiveFrom(hdoQueue);

    // This is what I'd like to be able to do:
    sbc.BeforePublish(context => context.SetHeader("my key", "my value"));
});
```

I believe there is a solution that involves implementing `IOutboundMessageInterceptor` but I can't find a way to attach my interceptor. There is a `ServiceBusConfigurator.AddInboundInterceptor` method but not a `ServiceBusConfigurator.AddOutboundInterceptor` method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My intuition was correct, I was able to do what I wanted by implementing `IOutboundMessageInterceptor`:

```
public class AttachHeadersOutboundInterceptor : IOutboundMessageInterceptor
{
    public void PreDispatch(ISendContext context)
    {
        context.SetHeader("my key", "my value");
    }

    public void PostDispatch(ISendContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Oddly there is no `ServiceBusConfigurator.AddOutboundInterceptor` method, so I just created one (by copying [the code](https://github.com/phatboyg/MassTransit/blob/efa7fc93ce504ca79bd391370db89e6c25bdc9d0/src/MassTransit/Configuration/InterceptorExtensions.cs) for `AddInboundInterceptor` from github):

```
public static class MassTransitExtensions
{
    public static void AddOutboundInterceptor(this ServiceBusConfigurator configurator,
        IOutboundMessageInterceptor interceptor)
    {
        var builderConfigurator = new PostCreateBusBuilderConfigurator(bus =>
        {
            var interceptorConfigurator = new OutboundMessageInterceptorConfigurator(bus.OutboundPipeline);

            interceptorConfigurator.Create(interceptor);
        });

        configurator.AddBusConfigurator(builderConfigurator);
    }
}
```

And then I attach it during bus configuration:

```
ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
{        
    sbc.UseRabbitMq();
    sbc.ReceiveFrom(hdoQueue);

    sbc.AddOutboundInterceptor(new AttachHeadersOutboundInterceptor());
});
```

Problem solved.

Comment: Any chance you did a PR for this?

Comment: @SonicTheLichen My lazy backside did not send in a patch for this. Apologies.

Comment: no worries, just curious.  I appreciate the info regardless!

Comment: does this solution apply to MT3 also?
(i can't seem to find how to run the following: _bus.Publish(myMessage, context => context.SetHeader("my key", "my value"));)

Comment: @Jackl56 I couldn't say, I'm no longer working on the project that used MassTransit.

Comment: If anyone read this: there is [middleware](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/advanced/middleware/custom.html) for that in MT3.